Azure DevOps - Reuse code between pipelines
I am using Azure DevOps Pipelines in the Cloud.
I have a repo where I have my code, and which I use to the pipelines.
In some pipelines I need to use some input from the user, which is a dropdown with a server (in the pipeline yaml file) option like this:
  - name: serverName
    displayName: 'Select Server'
    type: string
    values:
      - server1
      - server2
      - server3

If I want to user this servers selection input from the user (for example) for some other pipelines can I do this in some way which I could reuse the code instead of writing this code again in other pipelines yaml?

Unfortunately as of October 2024 there's no way to reuse parameters at the pipeline level.

Not expecting that answer. But thanks for your answer

@H.N. I feel your pain, I had a similar problem: a list of parameters used in multiple pipelines. I had to copy/paste it to every single one of them.

Yes that's what I was trying to avoid :( Strange that Azure Devops doesn't have a better solution for this. Thanks for your answer.
